# filter two array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am facing issues while adding or removing the object in an array with some conditions.I have 2 array finalArr and referenceArr.

1) Add and remove the Object is possible for finalArr array. referenceArr array is only for reference.

2) Object can be removed only if nonEdit is true in finalArr.

3) There are 3 properties should be compared number, type & nonEdit. for example 
 `{number: "8080", type: "abcd", nonEdit: true....}` object is present in both so it remain in finalArr but  `{ number: "6767", type: "xyzd", nonEdit: true,..}` this object is not present in referenceArr it should be removed.

4) The object which is not present in finalArr should be added. example this 2 object at not present `{ number: "7777", type: "efg", nonEdit: true..}` & `{ number: "8888", type: "xyz", nonEdit: true..}` should be added to the finalArr array.

```
let referenceArr = [{ number: "8080", type: "abcd", nonEdit: true,externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
{ number: "7777", type: "efg", nonEdit: true,  externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
{ number: "8888", type: "xyz", nonEdit: true, externalPort: false, position: "right1" }]

let finalArr = [{ number: "8084", type: "sdsd", nonEdit: false,  externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
             { number: "8083", type: "sdse", nonEdit: false,  externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
             { number: "8080", type: "abcd", nonEdit: true,  externalPort: false, position: "right0" },
             { number: "6767", type: "xyzd", nonEdit: true, externalPort: true, position: "right3" }]
```

/// Here is the final output

```
   finalArr = [{ number: "8084", type: "sdsd", nonEdit: false,  externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
                 { number: "8083", type: "sdse", nonEdit: false,  externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
                 { number: "8080", type: "abcd", nonEdit: true,  externalPort: false, position: "right0" },
                 { number: "7777", type: "efg", nonEdit: true,  externalPort: false, position: "right1" },
                 { number: "8888", type: "xyz", nonEdit: true, externalPort: false, position: "right1" 

}]
```

Please help me with this issue. I am finding a bit difficult.

Comment: does the double `finalArr` means, that this is mutated? please add your try.

Comment: its not double the final output of the finalArr array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: I was not filtering the final result in my initial solution so have edited my solution, please try again and let me know if it suits.
I have also included another potential solution below.

```
    function compareArrays(refArray, finalArray) {

        //Remove any values in final array which have nonEdit set to true and do not match an object in the refence array
        finalArray = finalArray.filter(finalEle => {
            for (let refEle of refArray) {
                return (finalEle.nonEdit === false) || refEle.number === finalEle.number && refEle.type === finalEle.type && refEle.nonEdit === finalEle.nonEdit;
            }
        });

        for (let refEle of refArray) {
            let foundBool = false;

            for (let finalEle of finalArray) {
                //If the 3 mentioned object properties for the current element in the reference array match any element in the 
                // final array. 
                if (refEle.number === finalEle.number && refEle.type === finalEle.type && refEle.nonEdit === finalEle.nonEdit) {
                    foundBool = true;
                }
            }

            //add the element to the final array if it is not already present.
            if (!foundBool) {
                finalArray.push(refEle);
            }
        }
        return finalArray
    }
    console.log(compareArrays(referenceArr, finalArr));
```

**Approach2**

```
    function compareArrays(refArray, finalArray) {

        //Remove any values in final array which have nonEdit set to true and do not match an object in the refence array
        let newFinalArray = finalArray.filter(finalEle => {
            for (let refEle of refArray) {
                if((finalEle.nonEdit === false) || refEle.number === finalEle.number && refEle.type === finalEle.type && refEle.nonEdit === finalEle.nonEdit){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });

        //Remove any values from referenceArray which are already present in finalArray
        let newRefArray = refArray.filter(refEle => {
            for (let finalEle of newFinalArray) {
                if(refEle.number === finalEle.number && refEle.type === finalEle.type && refEle.nonEdit === finalEle.nonEdit){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });

        //Return the two arrays merged together
        return newFinalArray.concat(newRefArray)
    }
    console.log(compareArrays(referenceArr, finalArr));
```

Comment: I am getting the output thanks :) but I am getting this object also  {number: "6767", type: "xyzd", nonEdit: true....} which should be removed because this object is not present in  referenceArr.

Comment: Updated the code to filter the finalArray before looping now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. Please try following to solve your needs:

```
updateArray(refArr: any[], finalArr: any[] {

    // Remove all entries in finalArr, which are not in refArr
    for(let i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i ++) {
        const entry = finalArr[i];
        // Sorry! I used the wrong array here
        const refEntry = refArr.find(
            (e) => e.number === entry.number && e.type === entry.type && e.nonEdit === entry.nonEdit
        );
        // Removes the entry form finalArr 
        // in case it's not in the refArr and nonEdit is true
        if (!refEntry && entry.nonEdit) {
            finalArr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    // Iterate over the refArray
    refArr.forEach(entry => {
        // Search for the entry in the finalArr
        const finalArrEntry = finalArr.find(
            (e) => e.number === entry.number && e.type === entry.type && e.nonEdit === entry.nonEdit
        );

        // If finalArr does not contain the entry, it'll be added
        if (!finalArrEntry) {
            finalArr.push(entry);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting the output thanks :) but I am getting this object also  {number: "6767", type: "xyzd", nonEdit: true....} which should be removed because this object is not present in  referenceArr.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong array inside of the first loop (see comment). Please try it again ;-)